# Drop down list not refreshed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one master and child record tables.. After creating master record, try to create its child group with out refreshing the screen, the filed named 'parent' drop down list wont show the one which we created initially. The drop downs will show the field 'parent' which we created initially only after refreshing the screen.
The code that i have added in controller for creating dropdown list as..

```
   public JsonResult GetGroups()
   {
       var activitygroup = db.ActivityGroup
           .Select(c => new
           {
                 DisplayText = c.ActvityGroupCode + " - " + c.ActvityGroupName,
                 Value = c.ActvityGroupId
           })
           .OrderBy(c => c.DisplayText).ToList();
       return Json(new { Result = "OK", Options = activitygroup });
    }
```

in view

```
ParentGroupId:{
            Weightage : 1,                                                                  
            title: 'Parent Group',                                  
            type: 'combobox',
            optionsSorting: 'text',
            options : '@Url.Action("GetGroups")' 
          //call the action to populate combo box,with id and display name                              
}
```

***Note:*** Datas are populated from jtable
please give solution for this .. ie populates data in dropdown without page refresh.

**I have 2 fields parent and sub the sub is a textbox field the data that i added in sub field get populated in parent field without any page refresh. this is the short description for this.**

Comment: You must give us a sample of generated html or a part of your jquery code if you use it. We can't help you with the server-side code.

Comment: here jquery is not used.. jquery is only used here to populate combobox from jtable.. is there any solution to refresh dropdown by using jquery

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of JQuery plugins to do that. 1st one given by google : http://www.appelsiini.net/2010/jquery-chained-selects. If you prefer, you can do it by yourself using Ajax in JQuery.

Comment: look sir:i have 2 fields parent and sub the sub is a textbox field, the data that i added in sub field get populated in parent field without any page refresh. this is the short description for this

Comment: i think thz code not be helpful for me

Comment: Your question is so messy !! `the filed named 'parent' drop down list wont show the one which we created initially` Ok, so the parent is the dropdown. What is the initially thing that is'nt shown ? What is "the one" ? `only after refreshing the screen.` you mean refresh the page ? Where is the link beetween the dropdown and the textfield ???

Comment: To best help you with your issue, please walk us trhough the code you used. Add snippets from the following parts: How is the DDL initially constructed? How is a call to the webserver triggered when the list needs to be refreshed? The code-behind for returning the results seems correct. How are the results being processed when they are returned to the browser?